# Spring MVC Controller - Model attribute - possible race condition?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Web Filter which will handle a post request, take a parameter and set it's value in the session. The value of the session attribute is then set in the model of another page which handles it. Eg.

Snippet from the filter

```
if (httpServletRequest.getParameters("MY_PARAM") == null) {
    logger.error("Parameter is null!");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter null!");
} else {
    logger.error("Parameter received redirecting to controller");
    httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("MY_ATTR", httpServletRequest.getParameters("MY_PARAM"));
    //redirect code
}
```

Then in the controller

```
@GetMapping("mypage")
public ModelAndView doStuff(HttpSession session)
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mypage");
    mav.addObject("MY_ATTR", session.getAttribute("MY_ATTR"));

    session.setAttribute("MY_ATTR", null);

    logger.debug(mav.getModel().get("MY_ATTR") == null ? "Attribute is null" : "Attribute is set");
    return mav;
}
```

99% of the time the log output is "Attribute is set", occasionally however it's "Attribute is null". How could this happen?

I've put a bit more debugging into the controller method. And it would appear the HttpSession is different to the one where the attribute is set in the Web Filter when this issue occurs.